# how to schedule a flink batch processing periodically

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a java application which does a flink batch processing of a batch obtained by querying the tables from the database and feed it into a kafka topic. How would I make this scheduled periodically. Is there a flink scheduler? For example, my java application should keep running in the background and the flink scheduler should periodically query the tables from the database and flink batch process it and feed into kafka(flink batch processing and feeding into kafka is already done part of my application). Please help if anyone has pointers on this.

Comment: Any chance finding solution to this problem other than Fabian's? Been looking at Flink API but could not find any proper way so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink does not provide a job scheduler.

Have you considered implementing the use case with a continuously running Flink DataStream application? You could implement a `SourceFunction` that periodically queries the database.

Continuous streaming applications have the benefits of fewer moving parts (no scheduler, no failure handling if something goes wrong) and a consistent view across the boundaries of "batches". The down side is that the job is always consuming resources (Flink is not able to automatically scale-down at low load).

Comment: thanks! we didn't want to use DataStream since it is inefficient precisely to our application and requirement. Thus, we moved to DataSet. If there is no Flink scheduler, i will probably have to do a simple Java scheduler which runs my Flink application.